# CSS renders differently when served through IIS

Tags: html, asp.net, css, iis

The file on http://tinyurl.com/qjrrsru is a zipped folder with one plain HTML page, 2 CSS files and 3 image files. These produce a panel with rounded corners. My problem is that this panel only works if opened directly in the browser or using ASP.Net Webserver. When I upload it to IIS it looks differently in the browser. What can I do so it appears exactly the same when served through IIS. I know many people have asked this question before but no solution has worked for me. Hence I thought I should share my files.

Comment: Does the browser console report any errors?

Comment: You want me to navigate to a different site, download, unpack and set up your web site, then try to identify some unspecified styling issue wich you want me to advise on. Seriously, life's too short.

Comment: do you open it with IE? Does your site run in intranet? Can you check if it opens in compatibility mode?
Do you have a css-reset in your app?

Answer (score 2):

Your image files don't have file extensions, IIS won't serve them without.

BTW Your code uses TABLE and IMG elements to achieve something that is handled quite simply by modern( and not so modern browsers) now.

I've recreated( not quite but close) here

http://jsfiddle.net/adrianjmartin/MBzRB/

using a couple of divs and a smal amount of CSS

```
<div>
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <div>&nbsp;<br/>&nbsp;<br/>&nbsp;<br/>&nbsp;<br/>&nbsp;<br/></div>
</div>

<style>

div{
 font-family:tahoma;
 border-radius:8px;
 border: #AECAF0 solid 1px;
 width:300px
}

div h1{
  margin:0;
  font-size:12px;
  background-color:#E0EDFF ;
  padding:8px;
  font-weight:normal;
  border-top-left-radius:6px;
  border-top-right-radius:6px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #AECAF0;
}

div div{
  border:initial
}
</style>
```

Comment: +1 for taking the time to dig into his source. (though re rounded corners, you might want to tell him about the CSS `border-radius` feature rather than just telling him what not to do)

Comment: @Spudley Your right. Hang on.